# java Get keycode from String

Tags: java, keyboard, key, lwjgl, keycode

How do i get the keycode from a string?
The keycode will be used on Keyboard.isKeyDown().

i have tried

```
char ch = key.charAt(0);
KeyStroke ks = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(key.charAt(0), 0);
int keycode = ks.getKeyCode();
```

but it gives me the wrong keycode,

and i also have tried

```
char ch = key.charAt(0);
int keycode = ch;
```

I got the same out of that, entirely wrong keycode

so is this **even** possible? and if yes then how?

Comment: @Andreas_D Ooops ..I missed.

Comment: @johnchen902 String... like "f"

Comment: @johnchen902 Nope, instead of 33 it returns 70(like all the other ones i've tried.)(key: F)

Comment: @user2418798 Are you using LWJGL?

Comment: @user2418798 Then check for [LWJGL's API document](http://lwjgl.org/javadoc/index.html?org/lwjgl/input/Keyboard.html). Maybe `int getKeyIndex(java.lang.String keyName)` is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

AWT/Swing uses standard ASCII values for key codes, ie `A` maps to 65 (ie, `KeyEvent.VK_A` = 65); however, [LWJGL](http://lwjgl.org/javadoc/index.html?org/lwjgl/input/Keyboard.html) uses a different coding scheme, which is why the values from derived from `KeyStroke` are incorrect.  Instead, you probably want to use `getKeyIndex` method:

> public static int getKeyIndex(java.lang.String keyName)
>
> Get's a key's index. If the key is unrecognised then KEY_NONE is returned.
>
> Parameters:
>          keyName - The key name